# R: adapting color key

Tags: r, colors

I would like to have the following color key:

[image]

Could someone help me to get this color key?

I've tried many options, such as:

```
col=rainbow(10,1,1,start=0.975, end=0.375)
```

but I can't find the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used function `colorRampPalette` to generate a function that interpolates colors between given colors.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster()
r[] <- runif(ncell(r))
plot(r, col = colorRampPalette(colors = c("red", "yellow", "white", "yellow", "green"))(30))
```

[image]